# How to set up strapi through Nginx with SSL

Tags: nginx, strapi

I'm working on digitalOcean droplets.

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#strapi-server

I've been trying to follow this guide for hours now, but I just can't get it to work.
When I try to connect, I get 502 bad gateway, don't know what that means. When I had just the 8011 port enabled through firewall and connected to the port directly through the DNS, it worked fine.

doing `nginx -t` says that syntax is fine, I tried restarting the service many times, the keys work.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf`:

```js
# Strapi server
upstream strapi {
  server 127.0.0.1:8011;
}
```

`etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```js
server {
        # Listen HTTP
        listen 80;
        server_name losslessly-api.djkato.net;

        # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificate/losslessly-api.djkato.net.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/losslessly-api.djkato.net.key;

        server_name losslessly-api.djkato.net;

        # Proxy Config
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://strapi;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

`./config/server.js`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 8011),
  url: 'https://losslessly-api.djkato.net',
});
```

`sudo ufw status`:

```bash
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8011/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere
8011                       DENY        Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8011/tcp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8011 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` and found out that my app wasn't listening on localhost, but the public IP.
Looking at my strapis .env file I realised that I set`HOST:{public ip}`, not `APP_URL:{public ip}`, meaning my upstream connection was on the wrong IP. Fixing my env file solved it.